# Cloudformation Template showing all nested changing with Null Changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation

For some reason, whenever we create a changeset, it shows that all nested resources will change but with a target of null and a null causing entity:

e.g.

```
 {
    "resourceChange": {
      "logicalResourceId": "LoadBalancerStack",
      "action": "Modify",
      "physicalResourceId": "our-resource",
      "resourceType": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
      "replacement": "False",
      "details": [
        {
          "target": {
            "name": null,
            "requiresRecreation": "Never",
            "attribute": "Properties"
          },
          "causingEntity": null,
          "evaluation": "Dynamic",
          "changeSource": "Automatic"
        }
      ],
      "scope": [
        "Properties"
      ]
    },
    "type": "Resource"
  }
```

What's the reason for this? Because for example this nested stack has these changes, it then propogates up to the other stacks.

The only reason I can think of is that maybe because some of their params are `hidden`, but I can't really think of logical reason why.

Comment: Any chance you ended up figuring out what this meant?